# Secure VPN on standalone Windows 2008 R2 server

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, ipsec, pptp

I have been tasked with setting up a Windows 2008 R2 server, and I need to allow VPN access to it.

I have RRAS set up which allows clients to connect via Windows VPN. Unfortunately, is uses PPTP by default, which I hear is really not secure. This page for example outlines is:
https://www.cloudcracker.com/blog/2012/07/29/cracking-ms-chap-v2/

I'd like to use a more secure method for VPN, but I'm really not sure where to go from here. The server is in a data centre and is not part of a domain. To move to something like IPSEC, everything I read involves domain level certificates etc, and the setup all looks very complicated.

I do not need the use of a domain on the server - I just need to allow a couple of administrators to connect via VPN, but I need it to be secure, or at least reassured that PPTP MSCHAPv2 can be made secure in some way.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction in either securing the default PPTP VPN settings, or moving to a much stronger VPN protocol without the need to create a domain?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up L2TP/IPSec on Windows 2008 R2's Routeing and Remote Access. I set it up a few months ago and it was quite easy and works great.

I used this site as a guide to figure it out: http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2010/10/how-to-install-vpn-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

SSLVPN is also an option, but I haven't tried it.